# Operação de bits

Tags: c, operadores, tipagem, bit

No meu primeiro semestre da faculdade fiz um algorítimo com a finalidade de evitar o desperdício de memória, apenas para teste.

Agora estou passando esse código para C:

Aqui está o código todo:

```
// 8 bits

// Aguenta até 4 slots (0 - 3)
// Valor inteiro máximo suportado: 255

void setBit8(int *pInt32, int index, int valor)
{
    *pInt32 = (*pInt32 & ~(0xff << index * 8)) ^ (valor << (index * 8));
}

int getBit8(int *pInt32, int index)
{
    return ((*pInt32 >> (index * 8)) & (0xff >> 32));
}

// exemplo de uso:
setBit8(&var, 2, 168);
printf("%d", getBit8(&var, 2)); // imprime 168;
```

E recebo o seguinte aviso na função `getBit8`:

> `warning: right shift count >= width of type`

A intenção é fazer com que uma mesma variável de 4 bytes possa receber até 4 valores inteiros dentro dela, podendo acessar ou modificar esses valores, como uma *array*...

Qual é o problema/erro?

Comment: Teria como fornecer o código que faz a chamada do método?

Comment: Vou editar minha pergunta!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei se o algoritmo faz o que deseja, ou algo útil, ou se vai economizar alguma memória, não parece, mas o problema é que potencialmente o tipo `int` pode ser menor que 32 e por isso pode ocorrer um problema. Então ou tem que usar um `sizeof(int)` para garantir que use o tamanho do tipo, ou usar o tipo `int32_t` que garante que tem 32 de tamanho, mas dependendo do compilador e sua configuração só a primeira funcionará.

C tem tamanho mínimos definidos e não tanto máximo ou tamanho fixo, o `int` pode ter pelo menos 16 bits e deve ser menor que o `long`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int getBit8(int *pInt32, int index) {
    return (*pInt32 >> (index * 8)) & (0xff >> sizeof(int));
}

int getBit8x(int32_t *pInt32, int index) {
    return (*pInt32 >> (index * 8)) & (0xff >> 32);
}

int main() {
    int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    getBit8(a, 2);
    getBit8x(a, 1);
    printf("%d %d %d %d", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/iS1y7g). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/nunqskex-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/SizedInt.c).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela a sua atenção, revisei o código e o erro estava justamente nessa parte. Aliás, essa parte era realmente desnecessária... Enfim, muito obrigado!

Comment: @MateusCosta dê uma olhada no [tour] como deve proceder.