# Dúvida em deslocamento de bits em C

Tags: c, c++, operadores, bits

Minha dúvida é em relação ao seguinte trecho de um código:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void){

    int teste = 0, x0 = 0, x1 = 0, x2;

    x2 = 1;
    teste = ((x0|x2) | (x1|x2) << 1);

    printf("Valor de teste: %d   ", teste);

    }
```

Quando eu compilo este código o valor apresentado para a variável teste é `3`, todavia não entendo o que o seguinte trecho faz, `teste = ((x0|x2) | (x1|x2) << 1);` Vocês poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Calculdora do windows no "modo programador" pode ajudar bastante a visualização dessas funções de deslocamento de bits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando é assim separe cada operação para ver cada passo ocorrendo, como você faria no papel.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int x0 = 0, x1 = 0, x2 = 1;
    printf("Valor de x0 | x2: %d\n", x0 | x2);
    printf("Valor de x1 | x2: %d\n", x1 | x2);
    printf("Valor de (x1 | x2) << 1: %d\n", (x1 | x2) << 1);
    printf("Valor de (x0 | x2) | (x1 | x2) << 1: %d\n", (x0 | x2) | (x1 | x2) << 1);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/hd9snA). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/arpbcygz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Operator/BitsManipulation.c).

Pela tabela verdade um operador de OU resulta em 1 sempre que pelo menos um dos operandos valerem 1. É o que ocorre das duas subexpressões que usam o operador de ou (`|`).

Acontece que pela [tabela de precedência de operadores](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)  o `<<` é executado antes. Este é o operador de deslocamento de bits (veja nos *links* abaixo). Então está mandando deslocar um bit para a esquerda. O número 1 em binário é `00000001`. Se deslocar um bit ficaria `00000010`. E este número em decimal é 2.

Finalmente será feito o último cálculo que é novamente um OU. Então haverá uma comparação entre `00000001` e `00000010`, os resultados das duas expressões de cada lado. Então o resultado será sempre 1 quando um dele for 1. Portanto resultará em `00000011` porque tem o 1 no último bit em um operando e tem 1 no penúltimo bit do segundo operando. O `00000011` em decimal é 3, o resultado final.

Exemplos e informações adicionais:

- [Operação de bits](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190575/101)
- [Como ligar um bit em um número?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/175345/101)
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91053/101
- [Para que servem os operadores | & << >>?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52949/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre os operadores & e &&?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190579/101)

Answer (score 5):

Esse trecho trabalha com o binário dos números, você deve entender o funcionamento de cada um:

**1)** O simbolo "|" significa "OU inclusivo" e o que ele faz é o seguinte:

O bit de resultado será 0 quando os dois bits de entrada são 0 (0|0). Em qualquer outro caso (0|1, 1|0 ou 1|1) o resultado será 1. Exemplo: se a variável var tem o valor 12 (00001100) e fazendo a operação com 6 (00000110), o resultado, var | 6, será 14 (00001110).

**2)** O simbolo "<<" significa "deslocamento à esquerda" e o que ele faz é o seguinte:

Desloca, para a esquerda, os bits do operando esquerdo no valor dado pelo operando direito. Exemplo: se a variável var tem o valor 3 (00000011), após var << 2, ela será 12 (00001100).
Dica: Em termos matemáticos, o que essa operação faz é equivalente à multiplicação do primeiro número por 2 elevado a segundo número.
Em termos matemáticos (A << B) é equivalente a (A * 2^B).

Então o que seu código está fazendo é mais ou menos isso:

```
teste = ((x0|x2) | (x1|x2) << 1);
teste = ((00000000|00000001) | (00000000|00000001) << 00000001);
teste = (00000001 | 00000001 << 00000001);
//O operador << tem precedência, então neste momento ele é executado primeiro
teste = (00000001 | 00000001 << 00000001);
teste = (00000001 | 00000010);
teste = (00000011);
teste = (3);
```