# Como saber todas as combinações possíveis de 0 e 1 em Java?

Tags: java, matemática, bit

Quais as combinações possíveis consigo somente com números **0** e **1** usando 5 casas (dígitos)?

Por exemplo:

00000
00001
00011
...
11111.

Queria guardar todas as combinações, mas não sei como descobrir todas elas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Usando While

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    int mask = 256;
    while (mask > 0) {
        if ((mask & i) == 0) {
            System.out.print("0");
        } else {
            System.out.print("1");
        }
        mask = mask >> 1;
    }
}
```

## Usando For

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
         for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
             for (int l = 0; l < 2; l++) {
                 for (int m = 0; m < 2; m++) {
                     System.out.println("" + i + j + k + l + m);
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Que loucura esse tanto de for dentro do outro :p

Comment: @diegofm também achei :)

Comment: Deu certo, não sei se eh a melhor solução mas me apresentou o que queria. SO precisei tirar 3 for por que queria com 5 casas e ai tem 8 mas deu certo. Vlw!!!

Comment: Tem como fazer com recursão também, não?

Comment: @Sorack tem sim, inclusive saiu uma resposta agora com recursão. Na pergunta que link do SO-EN tem recursão também.

Comment: `(mask & i)` o que é isso?

Comment: Isso é um and lógico @diegofm

Answer (score 16):

Solução simples, curta, performática, original, sem usar biblioteca, com pura matemática e um único laço.

```
class HelloWorld  {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) System.out.println("" + i / 16 % 2 + i / 8 % 2 + i / 4 % 2 + i / 2 % 2 + i % 2);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/VcxVuY). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/krlaopeq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Math/GenerateBits.java).

Se quiser o máximo de performance pode fazer:

```
"" + ((i >> 4) & 1) + ((i >> 3) & 1) + ((i >> 2) & 1) + ((i >> 1) & 1) + (i & 1));
```

Mas pode nem ter ganho porque o compilador faz otimizações e o código de cima pode se transformar nesse (duvido que ocorra no caso do resto virar *and*).

Comment: O que o operador `>>` faz?

Comment: @Sorack https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52949/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190575/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/175345/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7889/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10174/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91049/101.

Answer (score 13):

Uma maneira simples, utilizando apenas um `while` e sem recursividade:

```
int x = 0;
int n = 5;

// Enquanto x < 2^n:
while (x < Math.pow(2, n)) {
  System.out.println(
    // Converte de int para bin, formatando corretamente quanto aos zeros a esquerda:
    String.format("%"+n+"s", Integer.toBinaryString(x++)).replace(' ', '0') 
  );
}
```

Como o maior valor representado por `n` bits é `2^n - 1`, basta fazer o valor de `x` incrementar de `0` até `2^n-1`, exibindo a conversão de `int` para `bin`.

A saída será:

```
00000
00001
00010
00011
00100
00101
00110
00111
01000
01001
01010
01011
01100
01101
01110
01111
10000
10001
10010
10011
10100
10101
10110
10111
11000
11001
11010
11011
11100
11101
11110
11111
```

Answer (score 13):

Se existem 5 casas, portanto existem 2^5 combinações, então basta fazer um loop por todos as 32 combinações.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++){
      System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
}
```

---

Se quiser com o `String.format` com o `%05d`, isso indicará que terá `0` até ter 5 dígitos.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++){
     System.out.println(String.format("%05d", Integer.parseInt(Integer.toBinaryString(i))));
}
```

[Teste isto.](https://ideone.com/8lnqfg)

Answer (score 6):

Uma boa maneira de se fazer isto é tratar estas combinações como números binários (muito provavelmente essa é a real intenção).

Neste caso específico, é simples, o maior binário com 5 dígitos é **11111**, que é representado como **31** no sistema decimal - **11111(bin) = 31(dec)**.

Então, todas as combinações com 5 dígitos serão decimais menores que **31**, ou seja, o intervalo que será possível representar será de 0-31.

Indo um pouquinho mais a fundo, o maior valor representado por N bits é 2^N - 1.

Ou seja, 5 bits pode representar até 2^5-1, que é 31.

Aqui vai um exemplo em código. Perceba que você pode fazê-lo funcionar com combinações que tenham bem mais dígitos apenas mudando o segundo parâmetro do método `Math.pow()`.

```
class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // 5 é a quantidade de dígitos das suas "combinações"
        int num = (int)Math.pow(2, 5);

        for(int i = num; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            System.out.println(asBin(i));   
        }
    }

    private static String asBin(int i){
        return String.format("%05d", Integer.parseInt(Integer.toBinaryString(i)));
    }
}
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/@jfbueno/ptso205295)

Answer (score 4):

Da pra fazer recursivamente, para qualquer tamanho, utilizando o conceito branch-and-bound ou árvore bínaria

```
int count = 0;

rec(String palavra,int ind,int total,String[] saida){
    if(ind<total){
        rec(palavra+"0",ind+1,total,saida);
        rec(palavra+"1",ind+1,total,saida);
    } else {
        saida[this.count++] = palavra;
    }
}
```

No caso, a primeira chamada seria

```
this.count = 0;
int total = 5;
String[] saida = new String[(int) Math.pow(2,total)];
rec("",0,total,saida);
```

Answer (score 3):

Segundo [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22208514/java-how-to-output-all-possible-binary-combinations-256-different-sequences) resposta, você pode fazer algo desse tipo:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
        for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++){
          for (int l = 0; l < 2; l++){
            for (int m = 0; m < 2; m++){
               System.out.println("" + i + j + k + l + m);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Aqui ele vai escrever na tela todas as combinações possíveis, mas você em vez de printar, pode salva-las em um array

Answer (score 2):

Através de recursividade, e num código bastante legível, segue abaixo um programa simples de adaptar para N número de digitos através de uma árvore.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Start {

private static ArrayList<String> listaResultados;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    listaResultados = new ArrayList<String>();
    int numeroDigitos = 5;
    chamadaRecursiva("", numeroDigitos);
    for(String numero : listaResultados){
        System.out.println(numero);
    }

}

public static void chamadaRecursiva(String numeroActual, int numeroIteracoesEmFalta) {
    if(numeroIteracoesEmFalta == 0) {
        listaResultados.add(numeroActual);
    }
    else {
        chamadaRecursiva(numeroActual + "0", numeroIteracoesEmFalta - 1);
        chamadaRecursiva(numeroActual + "1", numeroIteracoesEmFalta - 1);
    }
}}
```