# Como isolar bits de maior ordem e bits de menor ordem em C/C++?

Tags: c, c++, bit, bitwise

**Preciso criar duas funções**

Uma recebe um valor inteiro e retorna outro contendo apenas os 8 bits de mais baixa ordem do valor original, com os demais bits colocados para zero.

A outra recebe um valor inteiro e retorna outro contendo apenas os 8 bits de ordem mais alta do valor original, com os demais bits colocados para zero.

Como seria possivel fazer isso?tive algumas ideias,mas nao cheguei a nenhuma conclusão que funcionasse,obrigado desde já.

Comment: Veja se isto ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/201392/101. Aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190575/101

Comment: Seria bom [edit] e descrever ao menos o que tentou e qual a dificuldade encontrada, assim dá ao menos para termos uma idéia do que você sabe e do que falta saber para chegar no resultado pretendido. Postagens que dão a impressão de "faça tudo pra mim" geralmente não são bem aceitas, mesmo que não seja intencional.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção Maniero e Bacco,obrigado pela dica,felizmente o amigo respondeu,tentarei ter cuidado com isso nas próximas perguntas,obrigado =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use os [operadores lógicos bitwise](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_logic_operators) para pegar os bits que você quer. A ideia é usar um número máscara e aplicá-lo em um valor para extrair apenas os bits desejáveis (que são descritos na máscara).

```
uint16_t value = 0b0100110111010001;
uint16_t MSB = value & 0xFF00; // resulta em 0b0100110100000000
uint16_t LSB = value & 0x00FF; // resulta em 0b0000000011010001
```

No caso do bit mais significativo (MSB), se você quiser inutilizar os zeros da direita deixados pela máscara, é só fazer um shift com a quantidade de bits a serem removidos:

```
uint16_t MSB = (value & 0xFF00) >> 8; // resulta em 0b0000000001001101
```

Answer (score 0):

Muito simples, vou dar o exemplo de inteiro de 32 bits, mas você pode aplicar facilmente em um short int. Primeiramente para você pegar os de baixa ordem, basta você fazer isto:

```c
unsigned int numero = 350000; // Inteiro de 32 bits sem sinal;

numero = numero & ((1 << 16) - 1); // Pegando bits de baixa ordemo

cout << numero << endl; // Resultado 22320

// Pegando bits de alta ordem
numero = 350000

unsigned int mascara = 0xFFFF0000; // Definindo mascara, em hexa.

unsigned int bitsAltos = numero & mascara; // Resulta em 0b00000000000001010000000000000000

bitsAltos = bitsAltos >> 16; // Movendo os bits 16 casas para direita
// resulta em 0b00000000000000000000000000000101
cout << bitsAltos << endl; // Valor 5
```